# ADO Plans Preview showing too many past sprints that are no longer needed

Tags: azure-devops

In the Azure DevOps Plans Preview how can I omit sprints which are not in my current quarter from appearing in the plans preview screen? Currently it shows years past which only clogs up he screen?

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this doc: [Review team Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops), Delivery Plans 2.0 is available for Azure DevOps Services.

In addition, after investigation,  there are no such ***settings***, ***filter*** or ***Field Criteria*** about this condition, so I am afraid that we can not omit sprints which are not in my current quarter from appearing in the plans preview screen.

But this is indeed a good suggestion. You can create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.